# Using openURL to make a call fails from button in table cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, openurl

I have a button in a table view cell and the following action to make a call using the title text of the button

```
- (IBAction)makeCall:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString     stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@",[button titleForState:UIControlStateNormal]]]];
}
```

This is failing (note: the makeCall action DOES get called, and debugging the title text of the button gives the correct value).

Using the SAME action from a button on the view (i.e. not in a table cell) works.

Anyone know why ?

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest to make an `NSString` for the URL and `NSLog` that string. Perhaps there is a difference between the two buttons.

Comment: Thanks, NSLog shows the string is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you attached your method to your button?

```
[yourButton addTarget:self selector:@selector(makeCall:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

You can always debug it by using `NSLog`:

```
NSLog(@"Yep, it does get called, `openURL` just doesn't work ...");
```

Add the line above below `- (IBAction)makeCall:(id)sender ... {`

---

Nevermind, I read you're already sure your method gets called. Add the following line instead:

```
NSLog(@"Yep, it does get called, `openURL` just doesn't work ...: %@", [sender title]);
```

If it contains any spaces or special characters (basically all characters except A-Za-z0-9) you may need to perform a little URL-encoding operation on it (or, if possible, just strip those characters away).